# How to deploy a spring integration component?

Tags: spring, deployment, spring-integration, spring-boot

I've developed a spring integration component that is to sit on a server and process messages coming in over an inbound RMI channel do some processing/filtering and then send out some messages over a different RMI channel.

Currently, for testing, I've been running it using a Main class that just loads the context, which sets up the inbound RMI gateway and it's working fine. But I don't think that this is appropriate for a production environment.

What is the best way to deploy this type of project to a server?

If I were working in a .Net I'd be deploying this type of application as a windows service, is that what I should be doing here?

The application that is sending me data is hosted in Tomcat, would it be a good idea to also run this application within the same Tomcat container (Current requirements are for both components to be on the same machine this may change)? And if so how?

I'm currently looking into Spring Boot, am I on the right path?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best would be Spring Boot, as it's made to easily allow running different types of applications. Also, you don't need Tomcat if you can run the same component with a simple Main and not using UI. Spring Boot, also, has a sample using Spring Integration [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-integration), so you should be up and running in no time.